# Relations and differences between outer/inner limit and Kuratowski limsup/liminf

Tags: general-topology, limsup-and-liminf

Let $X$ be a topological space. I am asking about the relations and differences between the following two different types of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of  $A_n ⊆ X, n ∈ \mathbb{N}$, a sequence of subsets of $X$.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#General_set_convergence)

> $\limsup A_n$, which is also called the **outer limit**, consists of those
>   elements which are limits of points in $X_n$ taken from (countably)
>   infinitely many $n$. That is, $x ∈ \limsup A_n$ if and only if there
>   exists a sequence of points $x_k$ and a subsequence $\{A_{n_k}\}$ of
>   $\{A_n\}$ such that $x_k ∈ A_{n_k}$ and $x_k → x$ as $k → ∞$.
>
> $\liminf A_n$, which is also called the **inner limit**, consists of those
>   elements which are limits of points in $A_n$ for all but finitely many
>   $n$ (i.e., cofinitely many $n$). That is, $x ∈ \liminf A_n$ if and
>   only if there exists a sequence of points $\{x_k\}$ such that $x_k ∈
>  A_k$ and $x_k → x$ as $k → ∞$.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_convergence):

> the **Kuratowski limit inferior** (or lower closed limit) of $A_n$ as $n →
>  ∞$ is  $$ \mathop{\mathrm{Li}}_{n \to \infty} A_{n} := \left\{ x \in X
>  \;\left|\; \begin{matrix} \mbox{for any open neighbourhood } U \mbox{
>  of } x, \\ U \cap A_{n} \neq \emptyset \mbox{ for large enough } n
>  \end{matrix} \right. \right\}; $$
>
> and the **Kuratowski limit superior** (or upper closed limit) of $A_n$ as
>   $n → ∞$ is $$\mathop{\mathrm{Ls}}_{n \to \infty} A_{n} := \left\{ x
>  \in X \;\left|\; \begin{matrix} \mbox{for any open neighbourhood } U
>  \mbox{ of } x, \\ U \cap A_{n} \neq \emptyset \mbox{ for infinitely
>  many } n \end{matrix} \right. \right\}. $$

**My attempt so far** (correct me if I am wrong):

$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n \subseteq \mathop{\mathrm{Ls}}_{n \to \infty} A_{n}.$$ 
*Proof*: For any $x \in \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n$, there
 exists a sequence of points $x_k$ and a subsequence $\{A_{n_k}\}$ of
 $\{A_n\}$ such that $x_k ∈ A_{n_k}$ and $x_k → x$ as $k → ∞$. For any open neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there exists $j \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k \geq j$, $x_k \in U$. Since $x_k ∈ A_{n_k}$, $U \cap A_n \neq \emptyset$ for infinitely many $n$. So $x \in \mathop{\mathrm{Ls}}_{n \to \infty} A_{n}$.

Similarly, I can prove $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \subseteq \mathop{\mathrm{Li}}_{n \to \infty} A_{n}.$$

**Questions:**

1. I wonder how to prove or disprove that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n
       \equiv \mathop{\mathrm{Ls}}_{n \to \infty} A_{n}$$ and $$\liminf_{n
       \to \infty} A_n \equiv  \mathop{\mathrm{Li}}_{n \to \infty} A_{n}?$$
2. If they are not equal, when will they be? For example, will $X$
   being first-countable suffice?
3. Can the outer/inner limit be represented in terms of operations on subsets, such as union, intersection, closure, interior, ...? I.e. in a simple way similar to the third type of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ in my comment below?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: For a sequence of subsets of a topological spaces, I have seen three types of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$. Besides the above two, the third one is $\limsup A_n := \cap_{i=1}^\infty \overline{\cup_{n=i}^\infty A_n}$ and $\liminf A_n := \cup_{i=1}^\infty \overline{\cap_{n=i}^\infty A_n}$. My question here is about the relation between the outer/inner limit and Kuratowski's type. [This previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/120885/kuratowski-limsup-and-liminf-of-a-sequence-of-subsets-of-a-topological-spa) is about the relation between Kuratowski type and the third type.

Comment: [This previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84601/limsup-and-liminf-of-a-sequence-of-subsets-relative-to-a-topology) is about the relation between outer/inner limit and the third type, although I now think [Andre's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/84828/1281) hasn't addressed it completely (see my last comment there), and I also hope if someone can give some insights there.

Comment: @One correction in my first comment: $\liminf A_n := \overline{\cup_{i=1}^\infty \cap_{n=i}^\infty \overline{A_n}}$ instead of $\liminf A_n := \cup_{i=1}^\infty \overline{\cap_{n=i}^\infty A_n}$.

Comment: You did not try (the same) examples (as always) based on constant or alternating sequences with values $\mathbb Q$, $\varnothing$ and $\mathbb R$ in $\mathbb R$, although these could help you clear the situation **before** you ask a question.

Comment: @DidierPiau: Thanks as always! If the sequence is constant i.e. $A_n = A$ for all $n$ and some subset $A$, then outer/inner limit and Kuratowski limsup/liminf are all $\overline{A}$. If the sequence is alternating $\{\mathbb{Q}, \emptyset, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{Q}, \emptyset, \mathbb{R}, ...\}$, then outer limit and Kuratowski limsup are both $\emptyset$, and inner limit and Kuratowski liminf are both $\mathbb{R}$. If I am right above, the examples don't tell if the two types are different and are not sufficient to show the two types are equivalent.